# UITapGestureRecognizer action don't work

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a problem with the UITapGestureRecognizer. I use this code :

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.SelectPictureAction(_:)))
    cardView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

and my function here :

```
@objc func SelectPictureAction(_ sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("card moment is Tapped")
}
```

The problem is I tap my card and nothing happen. I think the problem is I install a gesture in a UIView that is not init in the same class...

So my question is :

> This is possible there are a trouble when I add a `gesture` in a UIView called in another class ?

---

this is the code of my 3 class I used :

TableView Code :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(CardCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"Cell") as! CardCell
    cell.widthOfDevice = tableView.bounds.size.width
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        cell.doTheWork(statutOfCard: .selectMoment)
    }else{
        cell.doTheWork(statutOfCard: .goMoment(picture:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "img2")))
    }

    return cell
}
}
```

CardCell code :

```
class CardCell : UITableViewCell {
let cardView = UIView()
enum statut {
    case selectMoment
    case goMoment(picture: UIImage)
}

func doTheWork(statutOfCard : statut){
    switch statutOfCard {
    case .selectMoment:
        self.drawMomentPicture()
    case .goMoment(let picture):
        self.drawGoMoment(image: picture)
    default:
        cardViewHeightCon.constant = 300
        self.addCardShadow()
    }
}

func drawMomentPicture(){
    if(cardIsDraw == false){
        widthOfCard = widthOfDevice - (widthMarginConstraint*2)
        cardViewHeightCon.constant = widthOfCard!*ratioOfImage
        _ = SelectMoment(countUserMoment: 1, cardView: self.cardView, tableViewCell: self) // Here I call my class
        self.addCardShadow()
        cardIsDraw = true
    }
}
}
```

SelectMoment code :

```
class SelectMoment {
    let countUserMoment: Int
    let cardView : UIView
    let selfTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

init(countUserMoment: Int, cardView : UIView, tableViewCell : UITableViewCell) {
    self.countUserMoment = countUserMoment
    self.cardView = cardView
    self.selfTableViewCell = tableViewCell
    self.drawCard()
}
func drawCard(){
    cardView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    cardView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.SelectMomentAction(_:)))
    cardView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}
@objc func SelectMomentAction(_ sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("card moment is Tapped")
}
}
```

Comment: Is `cardView` a `UIImageView`?

Comment: @rmaddy `CardView` is a simple `UIView`

Comment: Sorry for the question, is the cardView IBOutlet connected?

Comment: @Kerberos It sometimes happens to me to forget that kind of silly thing! But in my situation this work because I can add view or components that I see in the simulator.

Comment: In your table view code, the code that adds the gesture recognizer is not there. So where _is_ the code that adds the gesture recognizer?

Comment: @matt I add one by one the class to show you and the gesture is in the last one ! the `selectMoment ` class ! Remove the down vote please

Comment: You've made the question worse and worse. Until this code appears _in the question_, my down vote remains. No one wants to click some link; _show your code_, properly formatted, right in the question.

Comment: @matt The question is now clean, can you help me please ?

Comment: Sure. You have a class called `selectMoment` (properly a class name should start with a capital letter, SelectMoment). But no code that you have shown ever creates an _instance_ of that class. So, based on what you've shown, I'd have to say that everything in that class is irrelevant; none of it ever does anything. As you rightly say, the "gesture" stuff is in there, but it might as well be nowhere, since there is no instance of that class. Why did you do such a weird thing in the first place?

Comment: @matt I edit my code for the capital letter, thanks. I edit also this `_ = SelectMoment(...)` After I called this class I just give a background yellow to the card view but this is for the exemple. I can't give all the code but i add some image and other view in the `drawCard` function

Comment: Great so now you make an instance of the class and throw it away, all in one line. Great. What good does that do?

Comment: @matt I'm beginner in development and if I create this class is just for not have so more code in the `cardCell` class because I need to design a lot of card. So in the class `SelectMoment` I draw the card. I don't need to use this class, it's just an extension the the `cardCell` class ...

Comment: "I don't need to use this class, it's just an extension the the cardCell class" No. That's the problem. It is _not_ an extension of the CardCell class. It is its own separate class. If you wanted this code to be in the CardCell class, then _put_ it in the CardCell class. Don't put it in some extra useless class.

Comment: @matt Ok thanks, so there are no possibility in swift to have an "extra" files to avoid 4000 lines of codes in the same class?

Comment: I don't say that. I just say that you need to have a way to make the two classes work together, and you are not doing that. See my new answer below.

Comment: @matt thanks to you to take the time to explain to a beginner... Can you start a chat that I can ask you a small question ?

Comment: Sorry, you don't have enough reputation to participate in chat. If you have a new question please as a new question; I'll be glad to look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is probably something like a helper struct:

```
struct SelectMoment {
    // ...
}
class CardCell : UITableViewCell {
    var selectMoment : SelectMoment!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.selectMoment = SelectMoment(...)
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Now your SelectMoment struct instance has a place to live in connection with your CardCell instance, and the CardCell can see it; with the right properties, they can even talk back and forth to each other with no problem.

Please note that that architecture is just a sketch to show you how to separate the powers of the two types. I don't know your intended use case. Maybe what you want is to be able to assign a SelectMoment differently configured to each different cell type. In that case, don't set `selectMoment` in `viewDidLoad`; allow some other class to set it (possibly through the initializer or possibly just by setting it directly), and respond accordingly. That architecture is called *dependency injection*.

Comment: See https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/dependency-injection-in-swift-a959c6eee0ab for a discussion of the dependency injection pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector param is wrong it seems, use like below one.

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.SelectMomentAction(_:)))

@objc func SelectMomentAction(_ sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("card moment is Tapped")
}
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when I add this i have the following error message : `Value of type 'SelectMomentClass' has no member 'SelectMomentAction'`

Comment: I have edited my ans plz check now by changing the method signature .

Comment: Thanks to your edit, this fix the error but still not resolve my problem.. I can't add gesture in my class, all gesture don't work ...

Comment: Your question is not much clear show your cell creation method code. You are adding target to one class, and your action method is defined in different class it seems.

Comment: Yes I do that because i have so more code if I write all in the `CardCell` class, I edit my post to show you the code of my 3 class.

Comment: see check your [target: self] part , you must define the action method in the same class for which you are setting the [target], here what is your self class  ? in that self class only you have to define its action method.